# Are there any tactics to work with preconditions with "and"?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

My goal is like below. Are there any tactics to solve these trivial goals?

```
Goal forall A (x : A) P Q,
  (forall y, P y /\ Q y) ->
  Q x.
Proof.
  intros. intuition. auto.
Abort.

(* a more complex version *)
Goal forall A (x : A) P Q R,
  (forall y, R -> P y /\ Q y) ->
  R ->
  Q x.
Proof.
  intros. intuition. auto.
Abort.
```

Comment: I guesss `eauto with proj2` should work. I don't know why it comes out it doesn't.

Comment: I think the reason eauto cannot use proj2 as a hint is because (to quote the manual) "The head symbol of the type of term is a bound variable". That is, the conclusion of proj2 is just an arbitrary proposition, so there is no head symbol to index it under.

Comment: In this particular case `firstorder` would work. A manual solution is to use `apply`, as it is smart enough to deal with conjunctions.

Comment: @Vilhelm Sjöberg That makes sense. Applying `proj2` has no restriction on goal and may cause too much useless search.

Answer (score 1):

The tactic `intuition` does not work because that tactic is designed for propositional logic (i.e. it dos not the quantifier in `forall y, R -> ...`  There is another tactic for this, it is called `firstorder`.  Try it!

Comment: sorry, I did not read Anton's comment.  I believe this should have been made an answer instead.